# Proper approach to Gamma-distributed data prediction with measurement errors in outliers

Tags: outliers, gamma-distribution, measurement-error

My task is to predict [Gamma-distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) data with a large number of extreme-valued outliers caused by measurement error (i.e. the machine that records the values intermittently malfunctions).

My objective is to **minimize Mean Absolute Error** of the data as recorded by the machine -- meaning errors in predicting the "bad data" that these extreme outliers are considered just as much of a failure as if they were errors in predicting the "good data". All that matters is the [Mean Absolute Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error) that the model produces on test data.

Taking a very large sample, I can illustrate the distribution of the outcome in my data in the following ways:

### Density Plot

[image: Actual distribution from giant training sample]

### Descriptive Statistics

```
> summary(train.raw$Expected)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
    0.01     0.51     1.43    17.15     4.06 33020.00
```

*Note: Don't be confused by the fact that the outcome is called "expected". It's not an Expected Value in a statistical sense. It's what machine recorded as the outcome.*

### Fitting of the Gamma distribution by maximum likelihood

```
Parameters : 
        estimate   Std. Error
shape 0.27855894 1.226094e-04
rate  0.01623498 1.408218e-05
Loglikelihood:  -18048793   AIC:  36097590   BIC:  36097618 
Correlation matrix:
          shape      rate
shape 1.0000000 0.5042223
rate  0.5042223 1.0000000
```

So, both the proportion, range, and variation of the outliers is pretty extreme here.

I am not sure how to proceed. I could exclude outliers from my training data, left-censoring the data to a certain range (i.e. 0 to 20, 0 to 60, or 0 to 150, depending on my methodological choices for detecting outliers), though even then the remaining data still follows a Gamma distribution.

### Density Plot with Outliers (Y > 115) Removed

[image: Censored Gamma Distribution]

However, when I do that, there are large absolute errors with test data, when one of the extreme values are encountered.

On the otherhand, I can try to fit a model without removing the outliers. The primary problem here is that there's basically 0 correlation between predictor data and "bad" outcome data, thus the model (be it random forest, GLM, or anything else) is very unstable.

I want to confirm that I should try to remove outliers / "bad" data from the training data and I could use guidance on finding the split between the natural ("real") high values in the long tail of the Gamma distribution and the measurement error ("bad") extreme values. Based on the subject matter, we only know that the maximal "real" values could be anywhere between 20 and 115.

I am also open to suggestions on the best algorithm or model for use in this analysis, given the distribution and large size of the data.

Comment: What about trying a variant of resistant regression, like the ideas implemented in R in `MASS::lqs` ?